# Calculate difference between two dates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have two columns date1 and date2 in `2/23/2022 12:30:26` format ,i want to calculate difference in hours. How to implement .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert two columns to datetime type then subtract at last get hours from timedelta object.

```py
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

df['diff'] = (df['date1']-df['date2']) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: the format is in 2/23/2022 12:30:26,  will it work?

Comment: @donaldsmith Yes, `pd.to_datetime` is month first by default